# How do I access profile fields?

Tags: users, 9

I have installed the [Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile) module. I am trying to programmatically load profiles. The code works, but I am not able to access any field value.

```php
class IdCardController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Init id card download.
   */
  public function initDownload(User $user) {
    
    $user_profile = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('profile')->loadByProperties([
      'uid' => $user->id(),
      'type' => 'personal_information',
    ]);
    kint($user_profile);
  }
}
```

Using `kint()`, I can see all methods are protected.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You could examine the Profile Entity class here [profile / src / Entity / ProfileInterface.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/profile/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Entity/ProfileInterface.php), showing you a list of public methods including its getter methods, eg.:

```
$profile->getCreatedTime();
```

Additionally and similar as with Entities in general, you can also call data via either `$entity->get('field_name')->getValue()` or `$entity->field_name->getValue()`.

See more on that here: [Get information from an entity/ Entity methods](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api#s-get-information-from-an-entity-entity-methods)

So if you have a Profile Entity with a field machine name `address`, then you could get its data like:

```
$profile = \Drupal\profile\Entity\Profile::load(123);
$profile->get('address')->getValue();
$profile->address->getValue();
```

Comment: OR `$entity->field_name->value;`